# Designing a layout with multiple ImageButtons and Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to make a layout like in the figure below (Each block in the 3 x 3 grid would be a ImageButton and each of the ImageButton has text and a small image in the bottom):-

[image: Layout]

I think i can use a TableLayout, but the problem is that I want to fit all the components in a single screen without any extra scrolling. When I used LinearLayout, the imageButtons where overlapping each other, how do I avoid it?

I want the ImageButtons to fill up the width of the screen, but match_parent is not helping. Should I fix the size of the ImageButtons. But I want the layout to work in all the screens, not specifically in only one.

If I include the buttons also in the TableLayout (as a separate rows), then they are of the size of the ImageButton, wrap_content is not effective. And I dont know how to place them in the centre.

Please suggest something. Any other layout suggestions? I am not using GridLayout because the App is for GingerBread (Android API 10).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:
- Linear layout, orientation: vertical - as an external layout
- Linear layouts, orientation: horizontal - for each line. Set layout weight for any of the 3 "items" in it to be 33.

Each item consisting of: image button, text and image - a linear layout, orientation: vertical, and the text & image: again, a linear layout, orientation: hortizontal.

Image Button: set width to fill_parent. You can match height accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this works fine.
However I i had written in the description, I had wanted the text and the small image to be overlapping with the ImageButton. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "the text and the small image to be overlapping with the ImageButton".

Comment: Hi Yar. I am sorry for the unclear explanation. I want to do something like [this](http://i46.tinypic.com/2z85jfd.png). As shown here, the whole background is the ImageButton.

Comment: OK. That will be a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout (better) containing all the 3: imagebutton, image and text. Inside the RelativeLayout you can position them any way you like (android:layout_alignParentLeft, ...Right, ...Bottom etc).